# How do I replace "this" in Java with something that works

Tags: java, replace, this, frame

I'm looking to get the showGUI() method work, the compiler says "this" is not a static variable and cannot be referenced from a static context, what would I use to replace "this"? I've tried test.main (test being the package it's in). The reason I'm using the static method showGUI() is because I need the method to be called from another static method, as well as the startup() method. Below are my two main classes.

```
public class Main extends SingleFrameApplication {

    @Override protected void startup() {
        showGUI();
    }

    @Override protected void configureWindow(java.awt.Window root) {
    }

    public static Main getApplication() {
        return Application.getInstance(Main.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       launch(Main.class, args);

    }

    public static void showGUI() {
        show(new GUI(this));
    }
}

public class GUI extends FrameView {

    public GUI(SingleFrameApplication app) {
        super(app);
        initComponents();
    }
    private void initComponents() {
        //all the GUI stuff is somehow defined here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to pass `this` to another function, e.g. the GUI constructor, you need an object, and showGUI is best left as a non-static method:

```
@Override protected void startup() {
    showGUI();
}

public void showGUI() {
    show(new GUI(this));
}
```

If you really need a static method, you need an object to work on:

```
public static void createApplicationAndShowGUI() {
    Main main = getApplication();
    show(new GUI(main));
}
```

or even better:

```
public static void createApplicationAndShowGUI() {
    Main main = getApplication();
    main.startup();
}
```

or even better, don't create any static method:

```
// in your context outside of the Main object
Main main = Main.getApplication();
main.showGUI();
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, using `this` in a static method doesn't make sense. `this` refers to the particular instance of the class, but `static` means that this is a method that does not require an instance, and as such doesn't have access to any member variables or methods.

Just make `showGUI` non-static.

```
public void showGUI() {
    show(new GUI(this));
}
```

Comment: then my tray method which is static cannot use it

Comment: showGUI() is called by startup(), which is not static. You're not showing any code examples where you're calling it from a static context. You need to tell us what you're trying to do. As others mentioned, you can create a new instance using `new Main()`, although having a function call `showGUI` actually instantiate a new Main object may be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

'this' means 'current object'. In static methods there is no current object. In your example, try replacing `this` with `new Main()`.

Comment: `showGUI` is already called by a non-static method. Why create a new instance?

Comment: Because the OP said he needs (or thinks he needs) to call showGUI in a static context.

Comment: my tray method is static and calls the method when the user clicks the open button.

Comment: also with this, my compiler says cannot find method GUI(test.Main)

Comment: you probably entered show(GUI(new Main())), try show(new GUI(new Main()))